# Joomla Password set by email

Tags: joomla, passwords, registration, joomla2.5

I am using Joomla 2.5.

On my site, when a user registers, s/he is sent a password and the user then has to log in and change it.  This annoys people as does most unessential stuff.  I want to go back to the standard enter your own password on the registration form, password creation and to lower the rules so that it is easy for users to register.  I have captcha and I will retain the email check but none of this created password that has to be change and needing a number, a capital letter and lower case.

I would like to know those two things...

Where do I set the password creation back to the enrolment form?
Where do I set the password rules?

I am sorry, as I am sure these points are covered somewhere already but I have been going through forums for days and am running out of places to look.

Answer (score 3):

The default Joomla registration form automatically allows people to type in a password of their choice. It doesn't have the option to give the user a pre-made password then make them change unless there is some sort of plugin out there to acheive this. If you are using another component for registration, simply change over the the default Joomla one. As for password rules, the standard Joomla component doesn't have any so you will most likely have to code them in or find a registration component from the [Joomla Extensions Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/)

Comment: Thank you for narrowing down my search :-)  Although I did not feel that there were any additions for registration I have discovered that this was being handled by Community Builder.  If anyone wants this feature I would highly recommend Community Builder.